# Windows Sharing file over network NetShareAdd Error 53

Tags: c++, windows, networking, share

I tried to compile this example from microsoft docs for sharing a folder over network however the executable gives an error.

Full Code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lm.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Netapi32.lib")
void wmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    NET_API_STATUS res;
    SHARE_INFO_2 p;
    DWORD parm_err = 0;

    if (argc<2)
        printf("Usage: NetShareAdd server\n");
    else
    {
        //
        // Fill in the SHARE_INFO_2 structure.
        //
        p.shi2_netname = TEXT("TESTSHARE");
        p.shi2_type = STYPE_DISKTREE; // disk drive
        p.shi2_remark = TEXT("TESTSHARE to test NetShareAdd");
        p.shi2_permissions = 0;
        p.shi2_max_uses = 4;
        p.shi2_current_uses = 0;
        p.shi2_path = TEXT("F:\\abc");
        p.shi2_passwd = NULL; // no password
                              //
                              // Call the NetShareAdd function,
                              //  specifying level 2.
                              //
        res = NetShareAdd(argv[1], 2, (LPBYTE)&p, &parm_err);
        //
        // If the call succeeds, inform the user.
        //
        if (res == 0)
            printf("Share created.\n");

        // Otherwise, print an error,
        //  and identify the parameter in error.
        //
        else
            printf("Error: %u\tparmerr=%u\n", res, parm_err);
    }
    return;
}
```

Exe command :

```
ConsoleApplication1.exe myShare
```

Error Shown :

```
Error: 53       parmerr=0
```

However the follwing from cmd works fine :

```
net share abc=F:\abc
```

I am  unable to figure out what actually the error is and how to resolve that. can anybody help?

I am on windows 11 and code is compiled on VS 2015 Community.

Comment: Error 53 is `ERROR_BAD_NETPATH` ("`The network path was not found"`).  You are passing `argv[1]` in the `servername` parameter of `NetShareAdd()`, but `myShare` does not appear to be a server name.  Do you have the same error if you set the `servername` parameter to `NULL` instead? Your `net share abc=F:\abc` command runs on the local machine, not on a server.

Comment: @RemyLebeau still this works, net share abc=F:\abc. why?

Comment: See the update to my previous comment

Comment: @RemyLebeau NULL as servername didn't work, However as you rightly pointed out it being servername `ConsoleApplication1.exe localhost` and `ConsoleApplication1.exe 127.0.0.1` worked fine. Many Thanks. 

Comment: This needs admin privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With admin privileges, servername `ConsoleApplication1.exe localhost` and `ConsoleApplication1.exe 127.0.0.1` worked fine.